# Quarkus - Not picking changes from jar

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-native

I have two projects A and B. A is dependent on B.

Both projects are build using quarkus native build with maven.
Quarkus Version is 2.7.4

I did the code changes in B but have not changed its pom version and kept the same version in A. The changes are not getting picked up in Project A during execution.
But If I change the pom version of B and also change its version in A, then it gets reflected in A.

I am not able to understand why its happening. Can somebody help, please.

Comment: Are you using quarkus dev-mode?

Comment: Can you try the latest [quarkus version](https://quarkus.io/)? 2.9.2

Comment: no not using dev-mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer, Quarkus and maven won't look for changes to artifacts they already have cached unless the version ends with -SNAPSHOT

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).